# Win10 IOT Core Compatible devices (those which pair GATT) - but not SensorTag?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10-iot-core, gatt

Can anyone suggest a simple BLE device (GATT) which will pair with a Win10 IoT Core system that is NOT the TI SensorTag?

I want create a demo but don't want to use that particular device.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no limitation to devices but only for dongle/adapter that need to check the [hardware compatibility](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/hardwarecompatlist#Bluetooth-Dongles).

Comment: Hello Rita, Thanks for the thoughts.  I understood that only devices that will pair can be used with Win10 IoT so I was looking for devices similar to the TI SensorTag but not exactly that one that would pair.   Is that correct?  If so, do you have any suggested sample devices other than the TI?